# Find the number of terms of the given series: $2 - 2\sqrt{2} + 4 - 4\sqrt{2} + \dots + 16$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, education, geometric-series

In this question, common ratio will be $-\sqrt{2}$ and if I use this value ($-\sqrt{2}$) to find the number of terms, I cannot get the answer.
Before, I solved using "$-\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}$" which is wrong method. Can you please suggest me to solve this?

Comment: Can you express $16$ in terms of $a$ (the first term), $r$ (the common ratio), and $n$ (the number of terms)? You already know $a$ and $r$ so you can find which term $16$ is.

Comment: So are you solving something like
$$
2(-\sqrt{2})^n = 16
$$?

Comment: A geometric series with first term $a$, common ratio $r$, and $n$ terms, has last term $ar^{n-1}$. So if you divide the last term by the first, you get $r^{n-1}$. If you know $r$, you should be able to get $n$ from this.

Comment: @GerryMyerson is  , where is the negative sign of  $(-\sqrt{2})^{n-1}$ in answer given below? can you help? please?

Comment: @TobyMak Can you show me the step where base is equal to compare the power. It MAY seems putting random number is n and getting the answer to OTHERS. So, I want that step where base is equal.

Comment: We're trying to solve $(-\sqrt2)^{n-1}=8$, madan. If $n$ is even, then $n-1$ is odd, and then $(-\sqrt2)^{n-1}$ is negative, and can't equal $8$. So we assume $n$ is odd, and then $(-\sqrt2)^{n-1}$ is the same thing as $(\sqrt2)^{n-1}$, and that's why the minus sign isn't there any more. Of course, we have to check when we're done solving that $n$ really is odd, and since it turns out $n=7$, we're OK.

Comment: Does my last comment settle the issue for you, madan?

Comment: Yes, It help me. Thank you. Many are putting the value of n first and solving the answer but my question is to find the value of n. Now, I feel, I got the full explanation. Thanks @GerryMyerson

Comment: OK. I'll repost my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm upgrading my comment to an answer, since it seems to have settled matters for OP.

We're trying to solve $(-\sqrt2)^{n-1}=8$. If $n$ is even, then $n-1$ is odd, and then $(-\sqrt2)^{n-1}$ is negative, and can't equal $8$. So if $n$ exists, it has to be odd, and then $(-\sqrt2)^{n-1}$ is the same thing as $(\sqrt2)^{n-1}$, and that's why the minus sign isn't there any more. Of course, we have to check when we're done solving that $n$ really is odd, and since it turns out $n=7$, we're OK.

Answer (score 0):

In GP $T_n=a r^{n-1}$ here $2$ and $r=-\sqrt{2}$, then $$2 (-\sqrt{2})^{n-1}=16 \implies (-\sqrt{2})^{n-1}=8=2^3 \implies n=7$$

Comment: can you please clarify the step after this $(-\sqrt{2})^{n-1}=8=2^3$ <br> can you please explain where is the - of $(-\sqrt{2})^{n-1}$. This is the part where I was confused while solving this question

Comment: where is the negative sign of $(-\sqrt{2})^{n-1}$, @ZAhmed help me please

Comment: negative sign in the common ratio comes from the fact that the signs of consecutive terms are different

Comment: @BenjaminWang I didn't get it. Can you please explain more? Is -ve sign ignored?

Comment: For $n=7$, we get $(-\sqrt{2})^{7-1}=2^3$. This is consistent.

Comment: @BenjaminWang My question is not how does that -ve sign come. My question is where does that -ve sign goes after 2nd step. ZAhmed is solving it assuming as there is not -ve sign there. So..

Comment: okay, the answer is seven. But, how did you deal with that -ve sign in 2nd step?

Comment: BECAUSE, to compare the powers the base should be equal, and to make the base equal that -ve sign was interrupting me, how did you deal that -ve sign?

Comment: $(-\sqrt{2})^6 = (-1)^6 (\sqrt{2})^6 = ((-1)^2)^3 (\sqrt{2})^6 = 1^3 \cdot (\sqrt{2})^6$, where we have used $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$ in the second step. If you still don't get this, revise your exponent laws.

Answer (score 0):

Since the $n$th term is $2(-\sqrt{2})^{n-1}$ then we have

$$2(-\sqrt{2})^{n-1}=16 \implies (-\sqrt{2})^{n-1}=8=2^{3}=(\sqrt{2})^{6}=(-\sqrt{2})^{6}$$

and hence $n=7$. Here we have used the facts that $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a}=a$ and $(-1)^{k}=1$ for even $k$.